# Understanding the 'necessity' of arguments of a forEach method

Tags: javascript

Documentation seems to suggest that in a `forEach` method, a callback function is a mandatory parameter and currentValue is a mandatory parameter of the callback function:

[image]

However this code - without a parameter of the callback function - works fine:

```js
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

a.forEach(function () {
    console.log(5);
})
```

How am I to understand when MDN positions 'optional' around some parameters and not around others?

Comment: Probably because using forEach without ever accessing the currentValue would be pointless

Comment: None of the parameters in a callback are mandatory. After all *you* supply the callback, so it's impossible for `.forEach` to fail because of the number of arguments it takes or doesn't. If you call a function with more arguments than it declared, nothing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to enforce that a `function` accepts mandatory parameters. However, without using the `currentValue` parameter, there is really no point of `forEach`; you do not necessarily need to use any of the other parameters, though. All of the arguments are still passed to the `function`, which you can see if you print out the `arguments`.

```js
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
a.forEach(function () {
    console.log("Number of arguments:", arguments.length);
    console.log("Current value:", arguments[0]);
    console.log("Index:", arguments[1]);
    console.log("Original array:", arguments[2]);
})
```

Comment: Thanks @hev1. Hmm annoying, don't know why they bothered putting 'optional' around some parameters when they're all optional.

Comment: @tonitone110 It is most likely because there is no point of using `forEach` without the `currentValue` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you don't use any elements of array, you just print 5. For main task any interaction of array you need the currentValue for do some manipulations with array

```js
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

a.forEach(function (currentValue) {
    console.log(currentValue, 5);
})
```